# Align cell contents at top

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, diagbox

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l | *{8}{c}}
     \diagbox[width = 10em]{Hold}{Modstander}
             & $A_{7}$  & $B_{7}$      & $C_{7}$      & $A_{8}$      & $B_{8}$      & $C_{8}$      & $A_{9}$      & $B_{9}$      \\
    \hline \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+2pt]
     $A_{7}$ & \mc{---} & $A_{7}B_{7}$ & $A_{7}C_{7}$ & $A_{7}A_{8}$ & $A_{7}B_{8}$ & $A_{7}C_{8}$ & $A_{7}A_{9}$ & $A_{7}B_{9}$
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I vertically align `$A_{7}$`, `$B_{7}$`, ... with `Modstander`? (I would like to raise `$A_{7}$`, `$B_{7}$`, ...)

I've looked a quite a lot of (somewhat) related answers on this site but I haven't found a solution to my problem. `:(`

Comment: Use `\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{..}`... or don't use `\diagbox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems sufficient to raise the header entries by `.5\normalbaselineskip` as both components of `\diagbox` is set using `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\raisehdr}[1][.5\normalbaselineskip]{\raisebox{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l | *{8}{c}}
     \diagbox[width = 10em]{Hold}{Modstander}
            & \raisehdr{$A_{7}$} & \raisehdr{$B_{7}$} & \raisehdr{$C_{7}$} 
            & \raisehdr{$A_{8}$} & \raisehdr{$B_{8}$} & \raisehdr{$C_{8}$} 
            & \raisehdr{$A_{9}$} & \raisehdr{$B_{9}$} \\
    \hline \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+2pt]
     $A_{7}$ & \mc{---} & $A_{7}B_{7}$ & $A_{7}C_{7}$ & $A_{7}A_{8}$ & $A_{7}B_{8}$ & $A_{7}C_{8}$ & $A_{7}A_{9}$ & $A_{7}B_{9}$
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

A possible [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Modstander}} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
  \textbf{Hold} & $A_{7}$ & $B_{7}$ & $C_{7}$ & $A_{8}$ & $B_{8}$ & $C_{8}$ & $A_{9}$ & $B_{9}$ \\
  \midrule
   $A_{7}$ & --- & $A_{7}B_{7}$ & $A_{7}C_{7}$ & $A_{7}A_{8}$ & $A_{7}B_{8}$ & $A_{7}C_{8}$ & $A_{7}A_{9}$ & $A_{7}B_{9}$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```